# No data sent with simple Laravel pagination query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

So I have a really basic query, and for some reason it keeps telling me that no response data has been sent.

Here's my function:

```
{
    $search = Input::get('search', null);
    $takeList = array(25, 50, 100);
    $take = Input::get('take', $takeList[0]);

    $users = User::orderBy('display_name', 'asc');

    if(!empty($search)) {

        $users = $users->where(function($q) use($search) {
            $q->where('email', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
            $q->orWhere('display_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
            $q->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
            $q->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
        });
    }

    $users = $users->paginate($take);

    return View::make('backend.users.home',[
        'users' => $users,
        'takeList' => $takeList,
    ]);
}
```

I keep getting `MY_IP didn’t send any data."

I have tried using `skip` and `take` instead of pagination. Which take and skip gets the users (I know because I use print_r to see), but does not with pagination. I looked in my laravel.log and it tells me it exceeds the maximum memory.

Doesn't make sense because it's getting 25 users, and they only have a username, email, display name and an ID. I can't see that taking up much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem.

I had imported a user list, and the date fields were null, and the pages that didn't work tried use that date.

Silly me.